# How to create a object with Parse REST API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, curl, parse-platform

trying to add a new object in a existing Users database.

here is what i have that i tried:

```
response = HTTParty.post('https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User',
      :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
                   "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY",
                   "Content-Type" => "application/json"},
      :data    => {"keys" => "test"})
```

also this is after a user is logged in and goes to a different page. I try to curl it through terminal and it says `{"code":201,"error":"missing user password"}` so i assume i have to pass the password over to the this controller from the previous? i have the session passed over if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be trying to create a new user like that. You shouldn't be using the private class name and you need to supply the appropriate keys and values:

```
response = HTTParty.post('https://api.parse.com/1/users',
  :headers => {"X-Parse-Application-Id" => "APIKEY", 
               "X-Parse-REST-API-Key" => "APIKEY",
               "Content-Type" => "application/json"},
  :data    => {"username":"XXXX","password":"YYYY"})
```

Comment: im not trying to create a new user, im trying to add a column under a existing user.